# matlab imread() read jpg error under linux

Tags: matlab

matlab7.10.0(R2010a)

I=imread('input-small.jpg');

???Error using ==> jpeg_depth
JPEG parameter struct mismatch: library thinks size is 632, caller expects 616

Error in ==> readjpg at 13
[depth,msg]=jpeg_depth(filename);

Error in ==> imread at 441
[X,map]=feval(fmt_s.read,filename,extraArgs{:});

Comment: Voting to close, there's no question here.

Comment: You are probably better off contacting http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html (include the jpg file too).

Comment: This looks very much like a corrupt jpg to me.

Comment: I agree with Jonas. Post a link to the jpg.

Comment: Searching google for this error indicates that this is most often due to a mismatch in the version of libjpeg compiled against and the one used while dynamically linking in runtime. This might occur with non-standard installs or on unsupported platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got this error with R2010b. There's no relation to the picture itself.

It was using the system's JRE. When I switched it back to the JRE shipped with Matlab it worked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I re-install matlab and the problem has gone. Maybe you are right, if the problem show up again, I'll try your method.